# How to divide one Duration by another?

Tags: java, division, duration, java-time

Given two `java.time.Duration` instances, how does one calculate the whole number of times one Duration fits inside another?

It seems obvious to use `first.toNanos() / second.toNanos()` but the Javadoc for this method introduced a tiny snag:

> If this duration is too large to fit in a long nanoseconds, then an exception is thrown.

How do we calculate this division without the risk of an overflow?

**UPDATE**: I am implementing the [Token Bucket Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket). To that end, I need to know how many "periods" have elapsed since last check in order to populate the bucket with additional tokens. **I cannot simply drop nanosecond precision** because rates may be specified in terms of nanoseconds.

Comment: 2^63 nanoseconds is about 292 years.... is that enough?

Comment: Can't you do like this value2-value1=difference, increment the count and if difference>value1 stop else do again. ?

Comment: @JimGarrison I am calculating how many "periods" have elapsed in a rate-limiter API. The absolute magnitude of a Duration is not relevant to this calculation.

Comment: @nimi0112 Yes, but it would be slow.

Comment: Java 9 introduced a `dividedBy​(Duration)` method that will do what you asked for. It returns a `long`, the “number of whole times a specified Duration occurs within this Duration.” It may still overflow and throw an `ArithmeticException` in corner cases, though.

Comment: How long durations does your rate-limiter API need?

Comment: @OleV.V. As long as possible. Users populate the bucket with `N` new tokens every `Duration` amount of time. I see no reason to limit them if I don't have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
/**
 * @param first  the first duration
 * @param second the second duration
 * @return {@code first / second}
 * @throws IllegalArgument of {@code first}, {@code second} are negative or if {@code second} is zero
 */
public static long divide(Duration first, Duration second)
{
    if (first.isNegative())
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("first may not be negative");
    if (second.isNegative())
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("second may not be negative");
    if (second.isZero())
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("second may not be zero");
    BigDecimal firstDecimal = toSeconds(first);
    BigDecimal secondDecimal = toSeconds(second);
    return firstDecimal.divideToIntegralValue(secondDecimal).longValueExact();
}

/**
 * @param duration a duration
 * @return the number of seconds in the duration
 */
public static BigDecimal toSeconds(Duration duration)
{
    return BigDecimal.valueOf(duration.getSeconds()).add(BigDecimal.valueOf(duration.getNano(), 9));
}
```

Comment: Why bother? If you do it in seconds, then a `long` covers `292,000,000,000` years.

Comment: @JimGarrison Jim, please don't downvote answers simply because you don't understand the need. There *is* a need and if you want clarification please post comments on the question.

Comment: @JimGarrison But a `long` with seconds would lose the nano-precision of the `Duration`. This code uses full precision, without risk of overflow.

Comment: *FYI:* `assert` is not a good way to validate parameters, since `assert` is disabled by default.

Comment: @Andreas Apologies, you are right. This code was extracted from `private` methods in my code where `assert` was appropriate. I have corrected the code.

Comment: @OleV.V. Fixed. Thanks for the head's up.

Comment: Thx for the fix. Now this is the answer that best covers the requirements. There is still the possibility that `longValueExact` may overflow and throw an `ArithmeticException`. If this is not acceptable, one will have to continue working with `BigDecimal` or `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 9):

When you turn to the javadoc you will find that the Duration class actually uses seconds and nanoseconds to express itself. And as written there:

> The duration uses nanosecond resolution with a maximum value of the seconds that can be held in a long. This is greater than the current estimated age of the universe.

So you should either use only the seconds value. Or if you really need the exact value (including the nanoseconds as well) then use BigInteger. Where you could go so far as to even include the nanoseconds in such a computation.

Answer (score 1):

For Java 9 and later, there's just [the method for this on the Duration type](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#dividedBy(java.time.Duration)).